# Один корень слов

Tags: словообразование

Какие из данных слов произошли от одного корня?

- завещание
- ветви
- ответ
- приветствие
- ветхий

Comment: Находила информацию, что это -

Comment: Завещание, ответ, приветствие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно этимологическому словарю Макса Фармера - это слова: ***"завещание", "ответ", "приветствие".*** Исторически в них выделяется корень ***"вет"***.  К тому же корню восходят и эти слова: ***"навет", "извет", "обет", "совет", "вече".***